# Convert XML Document to custom class object in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an `XmlDocument` with properties like `Title` and `ID`. I also have a C# class with the same properties that I did `Add-Type -Language CSharp -...`. Is there a quick and easy way of casting the `XmlDocument` or a child of it to convert it to the C# class?

**EDIT**

I'm using Powershell 4 and the XML looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Objects>
  <Object>
    <Property Name="Title">Foo</Property>
    <Property Name="Description">Bar</Property>
  </Object>
</Objects>
```

And my Powershell script looks something like this:

```
$code = @"
    using System;
    namespace CSnamespace{
        public class CSclass {
            public string Name { get; set; };
            public string Description { get; set; };
        }
    }
"@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp

$xml = [xml](Get-Content $path)
```

This doesn't work, but I'm looking for something like this:

```
$CSclass = [CSnamespace.CSclass]$xml
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: By C# class, do you mean .NET?  If so, you can open the document (get-content, etc.) and explicitly cast it as an XML document using $xml = [xml](gc somefile.xml)

Comment: Please, give an xml example, the class, and your version of PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell lets you address properties dynamically, like this

```
$pname = "Length"
"SomeString".$pname  # Instead of "SomeString".Length
```

Now you could go through your XML properties/nodes dynamically and assign the value to the C# object. For example if your object has properties `a` and `b`

```
$myObject = New-Object MyABObject
$myXml = [xml]"<root><a>12345</a><b>hello</b></root>"

foreach ($prop in $myXml.root | Get-Member -MemberType Property | select -ExpandProperty Name)
{
  $myObject.$prop = $myXml.root.$prop
}
```

Comment: this will do if something as simple as casting won't work. I will test this out tomorrow. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$document = [xml](Get-Content -path "C:\Path\To\My\XmlDocument.xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the reply marked as the Answer from TToni, I was able to get exactly what I needed, but with some tweaking. my Powershell code looks like this:

```
foreach ($object in $xml.Objects.Object) {
    $cs = New-Object CSnamespace.CSclass
    foreach ($property in $object) {
        $cs.($property.Name) = $property.Innertext
    }
}
```